# pgfplots: \thisrowno{} is an undefined control sequence?

Tags: pgfplots

A lot of code about `pgfplots` I found (also here on tex.stack) was using `\thisrowno{}` to address specific rows of a table. All of these had no additional pakages loaded than I do in the following example. But I get the error that `\thisrowno` is an undefined control sequence. What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
0.0  1
0.1  23
0.2  4
0.3  35
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x=\thisrowno{1}, y=\thisrowno{0}] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\thisrowno{0}` is used to access the content of a certain column in the context of an expression.

In this case, however, you merely want to specify which column to use for `x` and `y`, so you'd use `x index=1, y index=0`. If your columns had proper names, you could use `x=<column name>, y=<column name>`. If you really want to use the `\thisrowno` syntax, you could use `x expr=\thisrowno{1}, y expr=\thisrowno{0}`.

However, typically you'd use `x expr` to process the data, for example using `x expr=\thisrowno{0} + \thisrowno{1} * \coordindex`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. :) So much parameters and options in pgfplots, it's very confusing...

Comment: @FooBar: It is at first, but stick with it, it'll pay off! Very soon, it'll come very naturally.

Comment: +1 for your comment suggesting to *stick with it* `:-)`